# Does someone know how can i add gifs to a Nodejs art generative code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an art-generative nodejs code that generates images by unifying different layers on top of each other using PIL library. Now, i want one of the layers to be a gif but whenever i apply it it renders as a plain image even tho the file is a gif. anyone knows why? Here is the code: (there are two other files but are just to select de layer folders)

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require("canvas");
const console = require("console");
const { layersOrder, format, rarity } = require("./config.js");

const canvas = createCanvas(format.width, format.height);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

if (!process.env.PWD) {
  process.env.PWD = process.cwd();
}

const buildDir = `${process.env.PWD}/build`;
const metDataFile = '_metadata.json';
const layersDir = `${process.env.PWD}/layers`;

let metadata = [];
let attributes = [];
let hash = [];
let decodedHash = [];

const addRarity = _str => {
  let itemRarity;

  rarity.forEach((r) => {
    if (_str.includes(r.key)) {
      itemRarity = r.val;
    }
  });

  return itemRarity;
};

const cleanName = _str => {
  let name = _str.slice(0, -4);
  rarity.forEach((r) => {
    name = name.replace(r.key, "");
  });
  return name;
};

const getElements = path => {
  return fs
    .readdirSync(path)
    .filter((item) => !/(^|\/)\.[^\/\.]/g.test(item))
    .map((i, index) => {
      return {
        id: index + 1,
        name: cleanName(i),
        fileName: i,
        rarity: addRarity(i),
      };
    });
};

const layersSetup = layersOrder => {
  const layers = layersOrder.map((layerObj, index) => ({
    id: index,
    name: layerObj.name,
    location: `${layersDir}/${layerObj.name}/`,
    elements: getElements(`${layersDir}/${layerObj.name}/`),
    position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
    size: { width: format.width, height: format.height },
    number: layerObj.number
  }));

  return layers;
};

const buildSetup = () => {
  if (fs.existsSync(buildDir)) {
    fs.rmdirSync(buildDir, { recursive: true });
  }
  fs.mkdirSync(buildDir);
};

const saveLayer = (_canvas, _edition) => {
  fs.writeFileSync(`${buildDir}/${_edition}.gif`, _canvas.toBuffer("image/gif"));
};

const addMetadata = _edition => {
  let dateTime = Date.now();
  let tempMetadata = {
    hash: hash.join(""),
    decodedHash: decodedHash,
    edition: _edition,
    date: dateTime,
    attributes: attributes,
  };
  metadata.push(tempMetadata);
  attributes = [];
  hash = [];
  decodedHash = [];
};

const addAttributes = (_element, _layer) => {
  let tempAttr = {
    id: _element.id,
    layer: _layer.name,
    name: _element.name,
    rarity: _element.rarity,
  };
  attributes.push(tempAttr);
  hash.push(_layer.id);
  hash.push(_element.id);
  decodedHash.push({ [_layer.id]: _element.id });
};

const drawLayer = async (_layer, _edition) => {
  const rand = Math.random();
  let element =
    _layer.elements[Math.floor(rand * _layer.number)] ? _layer.elements[Math.floor(rand * _layer.number)] : null;
  if (element) {
    addAttributes(element, _layer);
    const image = await loadImage(`${_layer.location}${element.fileName}`);

    ctx.drawImage(
      image,
      _layer.position.x,
      _layer.position.y,
      _layer.size.width,
      _layer.size.height
    );
    saveLayer(canvas, _edition);
  }
};

const createFiles = async edition => {
  const layers = layersSetup(layersOrder);

  for (let i = 1; i <= edition; i++) {
    await layers.forEach( async(layer) => {
      await drawLayer(layer, i);
    });
    addMetadata(i);
    console.log("Creating edition " + i);
  }
};

module.exports = { buildSetup, createFiles, createMetaData };
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ;

Answer (score 1):

I was able to build a tool to do exactly this! it takes png layers and turns them into generative gifs. Its forked from an earlier version of Hashlips but I plan to update it to a more recent version soon.

Here's a medium article: https://jalagar-eth.medium.com/how-to-create-generative-animated-nft-art-in-under-an-hour-e7dab1785c56 on how it works.
And here's the repo: https://github.com/jalagar/Generative_Gif_Engine
Feel free to follow me on twitter: https://twitter.com/jalagar_eth for more updates. DM on Twitter or create an issue/discussion on the repo for a faster response.

You can see all 1k of them on https://opensea.io/collection/genesis-bouncing-ball. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. It’s because of helpful peers like yourself that we’re able to learn together as a community. When citing an article it's important to quote the relevant information here in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.